# Coefficient of $x^r$ of the polynomial $(1+x+x^2)(1+x)^n$

Tags: combinatorics

I've come to the conclusion the answer is this by multiplying both the first polynomial and the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$.

$$\text{coeff}(x^r)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $r=0$}\\
n&\text{if $r=1$}\\
\sum_{k=r-2}^{r}\binom{n}{k}&\text{if $2\leq r\leq n+2$}.
\end{cases}$$

Is there a simpler form or another way to find this?

Comment: It is correct for $r=0$ and for $2\le r\le n.$

Comment: Sometimes we take by convention ${n \choose k} = 0$ for integers $k < 0$, in which case the general expression is also valid for the cases $r = 0, 1$.

Comment: It might be easier to figure out by writing $(1+x+x^2)(1+x)^n$ as $(1+x)^{n+1}+x^2(1+x)^n$.  That gets you $n+1$ for $r=1$ and in general a sum of two binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

One thing we can do is to turn this collection of coeffiecients into an Arithmetic Triangle, similar to Pascal's Triangle. I've generated the first few rows below.

[image]

Something I notice is that we can give a very easy recursive definition for these entries. If we let $\delta(n;k)$ represent the element in the $n$th row and $k$th column, we have that Pascal's rule holds. That is, $\delta(n;k) = \delta(n-1;k) + \delta(n-1;k-1)$ with the initial conditions that $\delta(n;k) = 1$ for $n = 2$. Also, $\delta(n;k) = 0$ for the two placeholder values above and when $k < 0$ or $k > n$.

I can tell by looking at this table that there is some way to write these elements as binomial coefficients, but I haven't yet figured out the exact transformation.

Addendum: I realized that $1+x+x^2$ is related to the generating function for the Fibonacci numbers. So, inspired by that we can create a nice closed form for these coefficients.

Claim: $\delta(n;k) = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-2}{k-1}$ for $n \geq 2$.

We prove this by showing it satisfies the recurrence relation given above and induction $n$.

The base cases are easy to check.

The induction step is also easy to check. Suppose the claim holds for all integers less than $n$ for some $n$. Then,
$\delta(n-1;k) + \delta(n-1;k-1) = \binom{n-2}{k} + \binom{n-3}{k-1} + \binom{n-2}{k-1} + \binom{n-3}{k-2}$

Applying Pascal's rule twice we have
$\delta(n;k) = \delta(n-1;k) + \delta(n-1;k-1) = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-2}{k-1}$

So, the claim holds for all entries in the triangle.

In fact we can give another characterization by dropping down to the factorial characterization of binomial coefficients and playing with them a bit to see

$\displaystyle \delta(n;k) = \left[ \dfrac{n+k-3}{n-2} \right] \binom{n-2}{k-1}$